# Função que retorna vetor

Tags: c, array, return

Como retornar um vetor dentro de uma função? E como eu chamo ela no main?

Esse return no caso: (return vetor;)

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float UK (int mat[4][4], float w[3]){
float *vetor[4];
float res = 0;

    for(int l=0; l<4; l++){
      //printf("\n");
       float soma = 0;
        for(int c=0; c<3; c++){
          //printf("%tfd ", mat[l][c]);

          res = mat[l][c] * w[c];
          printf("Resultado: %f\n", res);

          soma = soma + res;

         }

         *vetor[l] = soma;
         printf("Vetor: %f\n", vetor[l]);
     }

    return vetor;
}

float *Limiar(float vet[]){

for(int c=0; c<4; c++){
    if(vet[c] >= 0)
    vet[c] == 1.0;
    else
    vet[c] == 0.0;
}
printf("Yl: %d", vet);
return vet;
}

float Delta(){

}


int main () {
int mat[4][4];
float w[3];

mat[0][0] = -1;
mat[0][1] = 0;
mat[0][2] = 0;
mat[0][3] = 0;
mat[1][0] = -1;
mat[1][1] = 0;
mat[1][2] = 1;
mat[1][3] = 0;
mat[2][0] = -1;
mat[2][1] = 1;
mat[2][2] = 0;
mat[2][3] = 0;
mat[3][0] = -1;
mat[3][1] = 1;
mat[3][2] = 1;
mat[3][3] = 1;

w[0] = 0.2;
w[1] = 0.2;
w[2] = 0.2;



Limiar(UK(mat, w));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não pode retornar um vetor criado estaticamente dentro de uma função. Utilizar esse ponteiro fora da função representa comportamento indefinido

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, poderia exemplificar?

Comment: vetor deixará de existir quando a função for encerrada, como uma variável local comum

Comment: Como que eu chamo no main?

Comment: Poderia usar passagem por referencia talvez

Comment: ou usar *float \*vetor = (float\*)malloc(sizeof(float)\*3)*, por exemplo para criar um ponteiro com 3 posições

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Montei um exemplo de como você pode manipular seu vetor na função espero ajudar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alterarVetor(float vetor[], int tamanho){
    float *ponteiro;
    float *ultimoVetor = vetor+tamanho;

     for (ponteiro = vetor; ponteiro < ultimoVetor; ponteiro++) {
     *ponteiro = 6;
   }

 }

 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
 float vetorOrigem[4]={0.2,0.1,0.0,0.1};

  alterarVetor(vetorOrigem, 4);


  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  printf("Vetor: %0.1f ", vetorOrigem[i]);
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora eu consegui :D

Answer (score 1):

### Problema

Vamos começar por perceber o problema:

```
float UK (int mat[4][4], float w[3]) {
    float *vetor[4];
    ... //instruções que não são relevantes para perceber o problema
    return vetor;
}
```

Aqui tem já varios problemas, olhando só para estas linhas de código.

1. O tipo de `vetor` é `float**` pois é um vetor de ponteiros para `float`. Logo o tipo de retorno da função deveria ser `float**`:

   ```
   float** UK (int mat[4][4], float w[3]) {
   //---^
   ```
2. Se criou um array estatico dentro da função:

   ```
   float *vetor[4];
   ```

   Não pode retorna-lo e utilizar fora dela.

   > Mas porquê ?

   Este array foi alocado no stack, no espaço que foi atribuído à função e todas as suas variáveis. Por este motivo quando a função termina esse espaço é marcado como livre, podendo os valores que lá estão serem eliminados a qualquer momento. Isto implica que qualquer acesso a um desses ponteiros vai gerar comportamento indefinido e mais tarde ou mais cedo um *Segmentation Fault*.

### Soluções

1. Alocar o array no heap através de `malloc`:

   ```
   float ** vetor = malloc(sizeof(float*) * 4);
   ```

   Tenha cuidado com esta aproximação. Embora seja util e necessária em vários casos, tem mais implicações do que parece. Não só lhe dá a si a responsabilidade de ter de liberar a memória alocada, quando já não precisar dela chamando [`free`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/), como lhe vai potencialmente fragmentar mais a memoria.
2. Passar o array já alocado para os resultados. Neste cenário a função recebe como parâmetro o o array a processar e aquele onde é colocado o resultado:

   ```
   void UK (int mat[4][4], float w[3], float *vetor[4]) {
       //              array de resultado aqui ----^
       //sem retorno
   }
   ```

   Neste cenário a chamada do `main`, considerando apenas esta função em isolado seria assim:

   ```
   float *vetor[4];
   UK(mat, w, vetor);
   ```

   Esta solução torna a gestão de memória mais fácil, mas em contrapartida força quem chama a ter de definir o tamanho dos resultados de forma determinística.

Comment: Fiz como está na explicação, mas apareceu esse problema: 
[Error] declaration of 'float** vetor' shadows a parameter

Comment: @HeloisaDiniz É porque não aplicou corretamente. Suspeito que esteja a aplicar a versão com `malloc`. Se for esse o caso a instrução que eu dei substitui a antiga que era `float *vetor[4];`, assumindo que corrige também o tipo de retorno

Comment: Não consegui...